# How come tool tips only work in IE?

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

I've been fooling around with tool tips- where you hover your mouse over a piece of text or an image and a pop up thing appears to offer more information- and I've found something odd: No matter what way I do it, it only works in IE. Not Chrome, not Safari. Why is that? Does anyone know of some other method that I could use that would work?

The main one I tried was

```
<span title="I am hovering over the text">This is the text I want to have a mousover</span>
```

but that's not working...
This may be a dumb question, I'm new to this stuff so bear with me. ;) 

Thanks!

Comment: It works for me on chrome, you should hover your mouse over it for a short while before the tooltip appears

Comment: This works for me in Firefox and Chrome

Comment: Not sure what the intention for this is, but have you considered mobile / ipad / etc users? There's no hover-tooltips there :)

Answer (score 0):

If you like cross browser tooltips that you can alter in appearance you could use http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/ which is an easy to use and widely supported way of adding tooltips.